# Arithmetic tree clarification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

```
                    +
                   / \
                 -    6
               /  \     
              +   (Java)/
            /  \     / \
           4    *    5  +
               / \     / \
              3   7    3  4
```

Given this arithmetic tree, what would the result be?

The answer I got is 30, but I wasn't sure the order in which are done.for example, 3+4 = 7, then should I divide 5/7? or 7/5? that would make a difference in the result..

Comment: 3*7=21, 21+4+6=31. how did you get -2 from the division?

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry I had the answer as 30 not 29. I assumed that you would divide 7/5. Thus the question on how you "read" the tree.

Comment: You generally read it left to right. So, it should be 5/7 and in Java this would be 0. So, the answer should be 31.